# How to run rosdistro command?

Tags: ros, rosdistro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use ubuntu 12.04 64 bits with ROS groovy.

I followed [rosdistro](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdistro) page.

I install rosdistro by these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-rosdistro
```

But I still can't run rosdistro on terminal.

```
sam@sam:~/code/groovy_overlay/devel/bin$rosdistro
rosdistro: command not found
sam@sam:~/code/groovy_overlay/devel/bin$
```

I found I have two tool similar with rosdistro:

```
rosdistro_build_cache  rosdistro_reformat
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/100556/how-to-run-rosdistro-command?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2013-11-12

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arthur Queiroz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23076/arthur-queiroz/) on 2017-01-24**:
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64bits with ROS Indigo, and I'm facing the same situation as you. Did you find a way to call "rosdistro [command]" on the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems the rosdistro script was marked as obsolete on https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdistro/commit/e49f56162e0105eb81abf3ba805b3b06e635e74c, but no reason was informed and the docs weren't updated. As the script was commented out from setup.py, it is not installed anymore.

---

Originally posted by [Arthur Queiroz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23076/arthur-queiroz/) with karma: 16 on 2017-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-01-25**:
Promoted as a right answer. I also added an obsolete notice on the wiki page referenced in OP.